# ¿Se puede pedir 3 valores por un prompt y almacenarlos para después editar un array?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy desarrollando un Crud en JS pero no logro hacer funcionar lo de Editar valores ya creados en un array.

Espero me puedan ayudar! de antemano, gracias!

Tengo esta funcion, que lo que hace es colocarme los valores del array en cada label perteneciente, pero no me los modifica :(

```
function Editar(columna){
  filaActual = columna.parentElement.parentElement;
  document.getElementById('nom').value = filaActual.cells[0].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('ape').value = filaActual.cells[1].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('pais').value = filaActual.cells[2].innerHTML;

}
```

Esta es la parte del HTML donde estoy ingresando los datos al array, la parte del Crud de Escribir y borrar si me funciona, solo me hace falta la parte de Editar los valores del array

```
<form onsubmit="onFormSubmit();event.preventDefault();Vaciar();" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="tablita">
          <table class="tabla" id="tabla">
            <thead>
              <tr> <!-- Horizontal -->
                <th>Nombre</th> <!--Vertical-->
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>País</th>
                <th>Opciones</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div class="caja">
          <label>Ingrese Nombre</label> <input type="text" id="nom" placeholder="Escriba aqui" required>
          <label>Ingrese Apellido</label> <input type="text" id="ape" placeholder="Escriba aqui" required>
          <label>Ingrese País</label> <input type="text" id="pais" placeholder="Escriba aqui" required>
        </div>
        <br/>
          <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Escribir">

        </form>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Si no compartes el código en tu pregunta, como te vamos a poder ayudar?

Comment: Tiene razon, ya lo coloque, muchas gracias

Comment: Es necesario un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) con el html y todo lo necesario para reproducir lo que comentas.

Comment: Necesitas implementar JQuery, con Dialogs... Echale un ojo al siguiente enlace: https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Para el caso de las etiquetas `<label></label>` considere reemplazar `.value` por `.textContent`. De esa manera, lograrás que el contenido de los `Array` pasen a las etiquetas.

Comment: Es decir, te cito el ejemplo de una: `nom.textContent = valor`

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir la parte _HTML_?